# vim: How do I syntax highlight a line so that one part of it is formatted as A and the other part is formatted as B?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I've been at this for hours today, researching online and reading the vim manual.  I'm about at my wits end.  I want to format lines with timestamps so that they have green text, while bolding the timestamps themselves.  For instance, If I have the following 4 lines:

```
1  [ 20:42:57 20190601 ] Apple car truck a whole bunch of other nonsense
2  ball baby zebra more nonsense
3  [ 20:43:12 20190601 ] dog blah blah blah
4  circle mouse rat up down left right b a b a select start
```

Then both lines containing the timestamps (lines 2 & 4) would have green text, and the timestamps themselves (**`[ 20:42:57 20190601 ]`** and **`[ 20:43:12 20190601 ]`**) would be bold.

My first thought was to just use a regex pattern to match all lines with a timestamp and color them green, and then use another regex pattern for just the timestamps themselves and make them bold, like so:

```
syntax match timestampline "\[ \([0-9]\{2}\:\)\{2}[0-9]\{2} [0-9]\{8} \].*$"
highlight timestampline ctermfg=green ctermbg=NONE
syntax match timestamponly "\[ \([0-9]\{2}\:\)\{2}[0-9]\{2} [0-9]\{8} \]"
highlight timestamponly cterm=bold
```

But that just results in the timestamps being bolded with no green text anywhere.

Then I thought that maybe I need to tell each syntax where to stop or start matching, like so:

```
syntax match timestampline "\[ \([0-9]\{2}\:\)\{2}[0-9]\{2} [0-9]\{8} \]\{-}\zs.*$"
highlight timestampline ctermfg=green ctermbg=NONE
syntax match timestamponly "\[ \([0-9]\{2}\:\)\{2}[0-9]\{2} [0-9]\{8} \]\ze"
highlight timestamponly ctermfg=green ctermbg=NONE cterm=bold
```

But that just results in the timestamps being green and bold with everything else being unformatted.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.  Why are the second highlight statements completely negating the first ones?  Shouldn't they just be formatting what they match and not affect things that they don't match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:help :syn-priority`:

> When several syntax items may match, these rules are used:
>
> 1. When multiple Match or Region items start in the same position, the item
>       defined last has priority.

So in your code `timestamponly` always wins and `timestampline` is never used.

You can get the effect you want like this:

```
syntax match timestampline /.*$/ contained
highlight timestampline ctermfg=green

syntax match timestamponly /\[ \d\{2}:\d\{2}:\d\{2} \d\{8} \]/ nextgroup=timestampline
highlight timestamponly ctermfg=green cterm=bold
```

Comment: This is terrific, thank you!  There's just so much to vim, I can't wrap my head around it.